# Two Contexts of OpenGL writing in the same memory

Tags: opengl

Is it possible that two opengl contexts which are running on 2 different threads have overlap in memory accesses because they are not aware of each other?

Currently, I have a code which is made of three threads which each has its own opengl context but when one of the threads are setting a `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER`, the content of a vertex buffer in other thread is get corrupted with the values of the other buffer. So, when the following code is run, the content of the vertex buffer in other context is getting corrupted:

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, m_transformation_buffer);
glm::mat4* transform_matrices = (glm::mat4*)glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 3 * sizeof(glm::mat4), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);
  transform_matrices[0] = m_projmat;
  transform_matrices[1] = m_viewmat;
  transform_matrices[2] = m_worldmat;
glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER);
```

Can it be a problem with `Opengl uniform blocks`??

Comment: Are those three GL contexts shared at all?

Comment: No. I have not shared them.

Comment: multithreading issues almost always are not caused by the code that's being executed right when the program breaks. We need to see much more of your threading setup and data structures to give any reasonable advice.

Comment: what vendor is your gfx? it could be also buggy driver related. For OpenGL are best suited nVidia cards.  For DirectX are best AMD. Have you tried a diferent HW setup?

Comment: @Spektre I tried it on both AMD and nVIDIA. I understood what was problem here. I did something stupid. So, I was calling the function which changes the value of `m_transformation_buffer` of a specific thread in another thread and it corrupts the opengl buffer which has the same name as `m_transformation_buffer` in the second thread.

I hate these stupid threading stuff of opengl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. It was bug in my program. So, I had two threads which each had a `m_transformation_buffer` in their context which contains the transformation matrices. I was calling the function which updates the `m_transformation_buffer` of each thread from other thread which causes the buffer which has the number as `m_transformation_buffer` changes with values that should go into ``m_transformation_buffer`.

So, simply I fill a buffer in that thread in my main thread, then signal the thread to update the `m_transformation_buffer` contents with that buffer.